# Error with conditional in a make file

Tags: makefile

I have a make file that is throwing an error. I believe that the problem is down to a conditional statement that I have the syntax wrong for but can't figure out what is actually wrong.

To be clear I am running the code using the command make {target_name}

The code is

```
ifeq ($(isDynamic), d)
    libExt=.so
else
    libExt=.a
endif
```

The error is 
    /bin/sh: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running a Makefile as a shell script.  You probably want to run `make` on it instead.  Possibly you want to turn it into a `make` script, although this usually isn't quite what people intend; make the first line

```
#! /usr/bin/make -f
```

(or wherever GNU `make` is) and `chmod +x` it.

Comment: That's what I do. make {target_name}

Comment: You may have to show more of your Makefile in that case.  Note that conditionals cannot be indented in Makefiles, the `ifeq`/`else`/`endif` keywords must start in column 1.

Comment: Again, show more of your Makefile.  You may need to put it in a pastebin to avoid reformatting.

Comment: It's not true that conditionals must start in column 1.  What *is* true is that they cannot be indented with a TAB character.  _Anything_ indented with a TAB character is passed to the shell as part of the recipe.  Make does not try parse the content indented with TAB in any way other than replacing variable values.